# Comprobar si una fecha es menor que otra en un consulta cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Me gustaria devolver todas las encuestas donde la fecha final sea mayor o igual a la fecha actual.

```
$this->loadModel('Encuestas');

    $fecha = date('Y-m-d');

    $encuestas = $this->Encuestas->find('all')->where(['fecha_final' <= $fecha])

    $this->set(compact('encuestas'));
```

Pero me devuelve todas sin hacer la comparación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo solucione asi

```
$encuestas = $this->Encuestas->find('all', ['conditions' => ['GETDATE() BETWEEN fecha_inicio and fecha_final']]);
```